# Can we have mouseover videos previews in SharePoint Search hover panel? like in Bing.com

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search

I have a scenario in SharePoint 2013 Search that I need to display mouseover video previews in hover panel, just like the functionality in  Bing search engine. Is this possible in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is available in SharePoint,Videos have an embedded viewer so you can take a look before clicking through.

Result Types! We don’t squeeze all of the above into a single hover panel for every result. Instead, Result Type rules determine what ‘type’ of result you’re looking at, and the correct hover panel will be shown based on those rules.

[Introduction to Hover Panel in Search 2013](https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/08/introduction-to-hover-panel-in-search-2013/)
[SharePoint 2013: Enhancing Video Search Results](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-enhancing-video-search.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but here I've a video content  in external source, which each video I can point out to a player URL, so I have configured a custom hover template, finally when I hover on result it doesn't load any player instead it shows  preview image in that place.